# Как добавить пункт в контекстное меню текстового поля?

Tags: windows, реестр, windows-8

Где в реестре можно отыскать раздел, ассоциирующийся с полем текстового ввода, и добавить в его контекстное меню некий пункт?

Comment: Я так понял, стоит задача запуск скрипта/программы из контекстного меню Проводника с передачей ему переменных из введенного текста? Почему бы тогда не добавить в контекстное меню стандартным способом (в реестре) вызов, к примеру, VB-скрипта (WHS), где при старте появляется диалог для ввода значения - InputBox?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Да просто дело в том, что хотелось бы, чтобы скрипт работал с введённым в текстовое поле текстом, а после - там же его и подменял

Comment: Мне видится решение в том, чтобы при запуске скрипта запомнить текущие координаты курсора. Нарисовать диалоговое окно для ввода параметра с сохраненными координатами. считать значение, обработать его в результат. А затем вывести результат можно и в виде предыдущего диалога, но уже с введенным результатом (естественно по требуемым координатам).